# How to access specific objects in django models?

Tags: django

I have the following model below:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    #Show only courses belonging to this professor
    classes = Classes.objects.filter()
```

I would like to know how to access classes that belong only to the "professor" above, because if many professors create Questions I dont want all classes to appear when the professor had nothing to do with those classes. I want only classes they created to appear.

I have tried:

```
classes = Classes.objects.filter(professor=professor)
```

where professor is a field in the Classes model, but this gives the error saying models are not loaded yet.

The classes Model:

```
class Classes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    session = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    days = MultiSelectField(choices=days_of_week, default="", blank=False)
    school = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="")
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

The Professor Model:

```
class Professor(User):
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    isProfessor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Professor'
```

Comment: show us the relationship between `Professor` and `Classes`.

Comment: shouldn't it be .filter(professor=self.professor) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the classes for a given `professor` (professor would be a `Professor` instance) you should do:

```
Classes.objects.filter(professor=professor)
```

Or use the reverse lookup:

```
professor.classes_set.all()
```

If you want to access to the professor related to a `Question` from the `Question` class, you can't use `professor` because this is not a `Professor` instance but a `models.ForeignKey` field.

You need to make a new method in the `Question` class to do what's intended, so you can access `self.professor`, which is the `Professor` instance related to the `self` instance of the `Question`:

```
def professor_classes(self):
    return Classes.objects.filter(professor=self.professor)
```

However, I find it quite weird that you want to retrieve the classes a professor has from the `Question` model. It just doesn't seem its responsibility. I recommend you move this logic elsewhere. Or just don't use this logic at all since using any of the couple of lines I showed is simple enough, there's just no need for additional methods.

PS: using plural class names is usually a bad idea. There are some cases where it is accepted, but you should avoid them overall. You can read more on the matter by simply googling it.

Comment: I want to retrieve the classes a professor has fin the Question model so they know what class that Question is associated with. Also, I still cant associate a Question with a class created by the professor. In the admin, I would like the dropdown menu to show only classes belonging to this professor creating the question, not all the classes that have been created.

Comment: If you want to know what class the question is associated with, why haven't you defined that relationship? Your current design does not reflect that. All you can do is get the classes through the professor, which again, is as simple as doing `question.professor.classes_set.all()` or `Classes.objects.filter(professor=question.professor)`, given you have instantiated a `Question` as `question`.

Comment: I can't get the classes through the professor because in the app that contains Professor and Classes, Professor is defined before Classes because Classes needs Professor to be defined first. Therefore, I cant get the classes for a professor because Classes is defined after. I was trying to do it this way before, but I was not able to make it work, this is why it is the way it is now. If there is a way to fix it, I would, but I feel that it is kinda late now.

Comment: The order the models are defined in has *nothing whatsoever* to do with what relationships you can define or what queries you can perform.

Comment: @thatguy the order of definition has no relevance in associations between models. [You can set up a foreign key by passing a string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). I still don't see what your problem is, how does my answer does not help. What is your issue exactly?

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is then. When I add the following in the Professor model, classes = models.ForeignKey(Classes, on_delete=models.CASCADE), I get Classes is not defined error. Im just confused and lost at this point.

Comment: @thatguy I just told you to pass in a string and you're still passing the class! Pass `'Classes'`, not `Classes`: `classes = models.ForeignKey('Classes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: Why cant I get the classes that belong to a professor through the foreign key professor? You posted that comment just a little bit after I posted my comment

Comment: @thatguy **you can**, who is saying you can't? I've been explaining this to you all this time.

Comment: How can I get those courses to appear in the admin when adding a question?

Comment: @thatguy that is a different question; which by the way, will you even accept this question as answered or not?

Comment: @dabadaba I was able to solve the problem from another question.